# Rails: 404 when GET /build-non-gmail-inbox.js.map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard, livereload

I have a very odd behaviour recently that our team started developing again our platform, which is in Rails + Foundation, fully dockerized.

We made a pretty big update in several features, and now I'm seeing in local and staging environments a 404 error over and over again, because something is trying to find `build-non-gmail-inbox.js.map` within any path or route I visit:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/ANY-PATH-I-VISIT/build-non-gmail-inbox.js.map"):
web_1      |
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
rollbar (2.15.1) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call_with_rollbar'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
rack-livereload (0.3.17) lib/rack/livereload.rb:23:in `_call'
rack-livereload (0.3.17) lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
  Rendering /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/layout.erb
  Rendering /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered collection of /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb [142 times] (46.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (96.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/layout.erb (99.0ms)
```

All that I could think could be related is that we use `guard-livereload` gem, and we updated the version:

```
gem 'guard-livereload', '~> 2.5', require: false
```

But in their docs I don't see anything related to this map.

Also, I don't see this error in the Network tab, so I don't think a JS of ours is making this request.

I've googled and find in all my source code and there's no match for `build-non-gmail-inbox.js.map`, not even for `build-non-gmail-inbox`

This is driving me crazy, can someone point me in the right direction?

## EDIT

After debugging and a little help of other devs, I found out that in incognito mode it didn't happen, so I thought it was a caching issue. But after clearing out all cache in the browser, still had the issue, so started trying deactivating extensions, and found the guilty, [an Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mixmax-email-tracking-tem/ocpljaamllnldhepankaeljmeeeghnid?hl=en) (that I have enabled for the browser I use for local and staging environments) was the guilty. Disabling that extension stopped the requests.

Comment: Thanks man! this is so stupid and I wasted 2 days on it!!

Comment: Mixmax being all up in our stuff...